# Riddle about number of children Mr. A,B,C have

Tags: puzzle

I have a riddle and I am stuck with it second day.

Mr. A,B,C have in total 6 children: 5 sons and 1 daughter. John has one child more than Mr.B. Thomas has the same number of childrean as Peter and John have in total(summed up). Mr.C has the same number of sons as Mr.B.

What is the name of Mr.A and how many sons has he got?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since Thomas has the same number of children as Peter and John have in total, we can conclude that Thomas has 3 children while Peter and John have 3 children in total. Since John has one child more than Mr. B, but can't have more than Thomas, we conclude that Peter is Mr. B and John has 2 children while Peter has only one child. Since Mr. C has the same number of sons as Peter, who was only one child, we know that Mr. C has at most one son. If Thomas was Mr. C, he had at most one son, thus at least 2 daughters, which can't be true. Thus, John is Mr. C and Thomas is Mr. A. Since we now know that John and Peter have the same number of sons, while John has 2 and Peter has 1 children, we conclude that both have one son and John has the only daughter.

Thus, the name of Mr. A is Thomas and he has 3 sons.

Answer (score 1):

Mr. A is Thomas and he has 3 sons.

no. of children of A = a
No. of children of B = b
No. of children of C = c
No. of children of John = J
No. of children of Thomas = T
No. of children of Peter = P
A+B+C=J+T+P = 6
John is not B and thomas is not B => peter is B.
2b+1+b+b+1 = 6 => b = 1
=> J = 2, T = 3
MR C has same no. of sons as Mr. B => John is Mr. C as there is only 1 daughter
=> Thomas is Mr. A and has 3 sons